# Add Page links programmatically to SharePoint Quick Launch

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, quick-launch

I have a solution that deploys a web part with a web page, and I would like it to also add a Quick Launch home screen link to the created web page.

[image]

I tried a little code sniplet, that I added to my Feature Activation event listener, but it's not working.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
 using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://mySiteUrl"))
 {
       using (SPWeb oWeb = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb())
       {
             oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
             // Create the node.
             SPNavigationNodeCollection _quickLaunchNav = oWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

             SPNavigationNode _SPNode = new SPNavigationNode("Link Title", "http://link_url", true); //i tried with false, too. It didn't work

             _quickLaunchNav.AddAsLast(_SPNode);
             oWeb.Update(); //added this since I've seen it in some examples, but not every example had it
       }
 }
});
```

Am I missing something really basic in this?

I even tried the method described here, but it was not doing anything: [Best way to programmatically create/maintain SharePoint Quick Launch menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041775/best-way-to-programmatically-create-maintain-sharepoint-quick-launch-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Use `_quickLaunchNav.Parent.Children.AddAsLast(_SPNode);`

and try using `SPNavigationNode` constructor with 2 arguments instead of 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, but the edits did not help. It runs the code, I don't get an error, or anything, but it's just simply not added.

Answer (score 1):

Your code which adds links to the navigations seems to be correct.

Maybe you have a general problem with your code...

You are in the event receiver and can use your reference to the site. No need to initialize a new SPSite instance or do something with elevated privileges.

**Try this:**

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using (SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent)
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb) { 
        {           
            // Add links to navigation
            SPNavigationNode listNode = new SPNavigationNode("Visitors", "Lists/Visitors/All Visitors.aspx");
            SPNavigationNode newVisitorNode = new SPNavigationNode("Register New Visitor", "Lists/Visitors/NewForm.aspx");
            SPNavigationNode siteContentsNode = new SPNavigationNode("Site Contents", "_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx");

            web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsLast(listNode);
            web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsLast(newVisitorNode);
            web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsLast(siteContentsNode);

            web.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using (SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent) - this line is giving me a casting error (Cannot Cast from SPSite to SPWeb)
Instead of that I'm using the SPWeb web = properties.GetWeb();
But no luck with it, whatsoever.

Comment: Oh, then your feature has the scope "Site", so the parent is a SPSite, not a SPWeb. I modified the code, should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Add link to Sharepoint Quick Launch programmatically :

```
// references
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation;

// code to add Navigation link
using (SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
    {
        using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
            {                                                
                        string headingTitle = "myPageTitle";
                        string headingUrl = "http://mysitename.com/SitePage/myPage.aspx";

                        // Get the Quick Launch headings.
                        SPNavigationNodeCollection ql = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

                        // If a Resources heading exists, get it.
                        SPNavigationNode heading = ql.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Title == headingTitle);

                        // If the Resources heading does not exist, create it.
                        if (heading == null)
                        {
                            heading = new SPNavigationNode(headingTitle, headingUrl);
                            heading = ql.AddAsLast(heading);
                        }                                         
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SPSite spSite = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent
using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
{
    SPNavigationNode listNode = new SPNavigationNode("Visitors", "Lists/Visitors/All Visitors.aspx");
    SPNavigationNode newVisitorNode = new SPNavigationNode("Register New Visitor", "Lists/Visitors/NewForm.aspx");
    SPNavigationNode siteContentsNode = new SPNavigationNode("Site Contents", "_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx");
    SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
    nodes.AddAsLast(listNode);
    nodes.AddAsLast(newVisitorNode);
    nodes.AddAsLast(siteContentsNode);
    web.Update();
}
```